# Javascript function not always firing

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function which fires towards the end of a page load.  It looks like this...

```
<script language="javaScript" type="text/javascript">
    showAdverts();
</script>
```

so in other words it fires without the user interaction.

I've never had any problem with this but recently a few of our customers are not seeing the results of this function which leads me to bleive that on some browsers it's sometimes blocked.  The prob has now occurred on ff, chrome and ie and would therfore appear to be browser independent.

Any ideas as to the random nature of this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose there are some requests without answers. Anyway without more code it's impossible to help you.

Comment: could you give us an idea of what `showAdverts()` does? also, are you seeing any js errors when the event isn't firing?

Comment: Better wait the document to load first: window.onload = function(e){ 
showAdverts();
}

Answer (score 1):

1. It is surely not random.
2. The users might have adBlock extension installed.
3. Javascript is an interpreted language. If any other javascript statement before showAdverts() fail, showAdverts will never even get called. Use chrome/firefox dev tools to debug that.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I just downloaded AdBlock and it blocked that part of the site.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I just downloaded AdBlock and it blocked that part of the site.

Comment: change your id's and classnames so that they do not contain the phrase 'ad'. Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by a few things like:

- It could be that your code has been removed.
- `showAdverts` isn't anymore the function you expected it to be (overridden).
- The code does work, but the thing it should display is blocked by an ad blocker.
- The server serving whatever it intends to display has failed serving content.
- Some error in `showAdverts` causing it to fail (like syntax, or error thrown).

There are a lot of things that *can* go wrong here. I suggest you take a look at the console what happened. If it has happened in more than a few browsers, you can say that it's the code, not the browser, is at fault.

Comment: i downloaded adblocker for chrome and indeed that part is blocked.  On closer inspection I realise it seems the part of the page i want to display is blocked before the javascript fires.

I'm using DIV's with IDs such as 

<DIV id="Advert">blah</DIV>

I am trying to show my own ads so that a good name but is adblocker using that to prevent it from showing ?